# How to force a page break in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to force a page break after a certain row of a sheet. Is there some analogue of Google Docs’ (and Excel’s) “insert page break” for Spreadsheets?

If there is no “native” way to do this, maybe there is some hack (using functions / add ons / whatever)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Open your Google Spreadsheet.
2. At the top, click **File > Print**.
3. Choose print setting **Print: Current sheet** (default).
4. Click on **Set custom page breaks** button.
5. Drag the lines to where
   the page should break (each rectangle will print on its own page). [To remove a page break, point to a line and click Remove icon.]

[image]

5. When you’re done, click **Confirm breaks**.

Source: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7663148

Comment: This is a life saver!

Comment: You must complete the print dialog steps to have the custom page breaks saved.

Answer (score 1):

You could also split your data up into different sheets (tabs on the bottom) then print all sheets. Not ideal, but it works for simple spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt method -

Add rows to bottom of first page (make row height larger if you need a lot of fill space)

Fill empty rows with white background and remove any lines and/or boxes

Click print - jiggle around until you get what you want

Comment: In the print dialog there's a setting to remove grid lines, so you don't need to worry about manually hiding them all.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best way to print "each sheet" is to freeze the header. 
Select the rows you want to print.
Print. under the print options make sure to select the print selected frames *and* print the first row. It is just about the same amount of work for a page break.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag from the top of the sheet.

There are thick grey lines in the blank square on the top left of the sheet. You can drag these lines and create a page break. If you are making boxes bigger when you are dragging, you are dragging the wrong grey line. Find the thickest line in the header of the sheet.

Comment: For me at least that is changing the rows that are frozen at the top of the sheet, not creating page breaks

Answer (score 0):

There are no page breaks, but..

1. Select the bit you want to print
2. Copy
3. File -> New -> Document
4. Paste in the document
5. Squiggle around until it's pretty

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> (for print page), then you'll see a button for "Custom Page Breaks". Slide it to green. Then slide the page break lines to where you want them to be when you print.

Answer (score 0):

I found the first answer correct but easier to understand when adding the following details. On a ***desktop***, add the google drive app,  then log into “google drive” - still on a desktop,  open your sheets project ( it will be here even if you had been working on a tablet since “drive” manages all the google docs, sheets, & slides suite of apps ) then select print ....make sure to select the ***google print feature*** ( not air print ) If you don’t have a printer set up on google print, it’s easy. A printer just needs to be on your WiFi network. It will walk you thru the printer setup after you select print. ( again, don’t select air print ) so having completed all these steps the print feature offered me page breaks as a option. 
 I was not able to add page breaks using just the sheets app on my iPad Pro and hitting print. ( but the instructions didn’t say stay in the sheets app )  I hope this helps someone else as I was very frustrated trying to accomplish this without trashing most of a project.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt method - worked for me. just keep Scale and Margin settings through out edit.

Scale Settings must be kept all through out, I chose 'fit to width' and continued to margin

Margin Settings must be also kept through out, I chose 'wide' and continued adding rows.

[image: Google Sheets Print settings]