# Page breaks/page view similar to Excel in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Excel you can turn on "page view" mode which allows you to see where the page breaks are in a document, and insert header and footers. This is very useful for being able to generate invoices as you can get an idea of how a page looks before you turn it into a PDF.

Is this possible in Google Spreadsheets? I'm aware that you can't set a header and footer, which is okay for me, but I'd like to be able to know where the page breaks were.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

When this question was posted, in 2017, it was not possible to view the page breaks on the normal view. If you are still looking for this feature, please submit a feature request by using Google Feedback.

## Workarounds

You might use the print preview feature and the set custom page breaks as a workaround.

1. Click on the **Help** menu
2. On the search box type `print`.
   This will open the Print view.
3. If you need to adjust the page breaks, on the right panel, click **SET CUSTOM PAGE BREAKS**.

## How to submit a feature request to Google

To submit a feature request by using Google Feedback from a Google spreadsheet, do the following:

1. Open a spreadsheet on Google Sheets
2. Click on **Help** > **Help Sheets Improve**
3. Fill up the feedback form and submit it.

## Related

- [How to force a page break in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/72823/88163)

## References

Notes: As of October 2023 the below links are broken but they might still be helpful to find the referred content.

- https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/QmU767bXKHI/5HqLlVrqCQAJ (posted on 12/14/16 UTC -6)
- https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/HAj2Jzna8aU/9ZbwUHqfEgAJ (posted on 11/13/15 UTC -6 and marked as best answer)

Answer (score 2):

Click file -> print

Then click on "Set custom page breaks."

After that you can drag the lines to force the page breaks

Source: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7663148

Comment: The question is how to view/show the page breaks in the normal editing screen.  Not how to set custom breaks.