# Google sheets truncates large cell when printing

Tags: google-sheets, printing

Newbie here so...

I am gathering survey results that contain open ended text responses. Some of the responses are quite large. Online, Google Sheets provides a thumb within the cell to scroll through the entire response. However, when I print the sheet, extremely large cells are truncated to fit on the page. Smaller, but still large cells, force a page break so that the entire row will fit on the next page, leaving the previous page with a large amount of wasted space.

Is there a way to force Sheets to print the entire contents of a cell, even if it means "wrapping" onto a second page?

All cells are aligned left and top. All cells are wrapped.

I can't share a doc but here are screenshots of the print function that illustrates what I am describing. I hope you can read them.

[image: wasted space]

[image: truncated response]

[image: truncated response]

Comment: we need more info.  Is the formatting in your cells set to wrap text?  Can you give us access to a demo sheet with sample (nonsense) text that we can play with?

Comment: Apparently you haven't reviewed all the print settings, like the page breaks. [How to force a page break in Google Spreadsheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/72823/88163). Please review the Google Sheets help article about the print options as well the questions already posted in the site, add what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that we need more info to test it specifically in this case
Two things I can tell you to look is:

1. If "Text Wrapping" is set to "Wrap"

[image]

2. When you select "Resize Rows" with right-click in the rows, if it says: "Fit to Data". That option you had to "scroll" would be replaced by this resize process, maybe you can enable it just before printing and then disable it again if it's more confortable to navigate online

[image]

[image]

Comment: All cells are set to wrap. When I looked at the Resize Row is is already set to "Fit to Data"

Comment: Mmm, at least by your given example there are two ways you can go, considering that the other columns have far less information you could shrink all of them a little bit in order to fit the tallest rows in one page. Or maybe even set to landscape orientation and widen all that you need that column. I don't think there's an already set option to accomplish this either way, but maybe just by readjusting it you can work it out ;)